# SubQuery works in IMPALA but not HIVE

Tags: hadoop, hive, impala

I'm trying to understand why the following subquery will work in Impala and not Hive.

```
    select * from MySchema.MyTable where identifier not in 
     (select identifier from schema.table where status_code in (1,2,3));
```

EDIT:

Added the error

> Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException [Error
>   10249]: line 1:55 Unsupported SubQuery Expression 'identifier':
>   Correlating expression cannot contain unqualified column references.

Comment: Try with an alias to subquery, it might work that way

Comment: What is the version of hive used?

Answer (score 0):

Issue could be because of 'identifier' in both queries, in main query and inner subquery. Explicitly mentioning which 'identifier' you are referring to like 'mytable.identifier' should resolve this issue.

This is probably an issue with Hive that has been fixed in recent versions and issue is not reproduced in hive 3.1.0.

If you are still facing the issue, let us know the hive version you are using and DDL statements used to create tables.